# Update svelte store while subscribed to another

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm not sure this is possible but I need to update a svelte store while it is subscribed to another store.
Here's an example of what I mean.
Is this doable or what would be the best solution?

```
import { languageStore, appConfig } from "$lib/stores.js";

let productAppConfig;

// Subscribe to this store when language changes
languageStore.subscribe(lang => {
    init({
        fallbackLocale: 'en',
        initialLocale: lang,
    });
    // I get an error whenever I try to update this store inside here
    // appConfig.update()
});

// Set up product app configuration
productAppConfig = {
    title: 'Bike',
    video: {
        id: 'y_QNep4T17M', // YouTube video id
        steps: [
            {
                title: $json('bike.videoSteps')[0].title,
                seek: 10
            }...
        ]
    },
    locale: 'bike',
    glossary: true  
}
onMount( () => {
    appConfig.update( ( value ) => { 
        return value = productAppConfig 
    }) 
})
```

Comment: (That is not how `update` should be used. Assigning `value` does nothing and it could just be replaced with `appConfig.set(productAppConfig)`)

Comment: This example is very convoluted. Try to create a minimal reproducible example that is self contained; this has various variables that are nowhere to be seen. Also, if you get an error, include what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if one store depends on another, it should be a [`derived` store](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-derived). In this case, if the config is dependent on localization, it should derive from that. If other stores are needed as data sources, e.g. some base config, they can be included as well.

So you get something like:

```js
const appConfig = derived(
  [languageStore, baseConfigStore],
  ([lang, config]) => {
    // create new app config object using `lang` & `config` and return it
  }
);
```

With this, `appConfig` is read-only and will update whenever the stores it is based on are changed.